# Why does my var folder contain brute-force.ini?

Tags: magento-1.9

In the var folder, a file has suddenly appeared called `brute-force.ini`.

Is it harmful or not? Can I delete this file?

Answer (score 9):

There is this awesome tool called google. It usually helps to look there first ;)

First result:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/brute-force-ini/m-p/54215#M2288

This file is saved when Magento detects failed login attemps to the downloader.
(This feature was introduced on Magento 1.9.3)

Comment: Google is a great tool indeed, but there's nothing wrong with asking the question here for some more background :)

Comment: @mizuti, there might be nothing wrong with that, but still: google first, then ask a question here. It's always better to do some research yourself..

Comment: Someone has to ask them first before they end up in Google.

Comment: And...,  someone did. Practically verbatim the same question.  I for one, having found a file called brute force, on a live server,  not knowing what it was,  would be on Google faster than a mammoth steak would sizzle on a BBQ.

Comment: And guess where the first search result for this question now leads to...?!